# Detect & Read Any Outbound Audio Signals iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio

I'm just beginning my research into this question and simply because the need for a fast turn around I thought I would post the question here while I continue research on my own.

The first question I have is, is it possible to detect the device's outgoing audio signal(s) - from any source - using CoreAudio or any of the audio frameworks (or combination of) listed in the dev library?

My instinct tells me this is locked down.

Has anyone any experience with this?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can only detect if its playing or not with using

`[[AVAudioSession sharedInstance] secondaryAudioShouldBeSilencedHint]`

> Will be true when another application with a non-mixable audio session
>   is playing audio